# Are there any differences between "navigationController?.pushViewController" and "performSegue"

Tags: swift, segue

Are these guys both Pushe a view controller onto the receiver’s stack and updates the display? What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

A segue is basically a transition between `viewControllers` that work over `navigationController`. and `pushViewController` is a method to push the viewController in navigation stack.

i found resource on reddit and apple fourm

https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/7mqahx/difference_between_segue_and_push/

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4307